# Handling immutable prefixes in text fields

Tags: forms, web-app

We have a web form where some of the field values have required prefixes, which identify the namespace. (This is established business logic that will not be changing.)

**Example:** If the user wants to create an artifact for `johndoe`, that artifact name will begin `johndoe_` and continue with the value entered into the field.

I want to present the form in a way where it will be clear that the string `johndoe_` (1) will be part of the artifact name, and (2) the prefix cannot be changed.

Here's a mock-up of the currently-implemented solution. I think this is (1) a little homely and (2) not very clear for a new user. Is there a better way to present this?

[image: Form fields with required prefixes]

Comment: Would a similar use case be like creating a slack team where you can choose the subdomain but the ...slack.com is static? Maybe you could take some inspiration from that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple variations:

1. you can encase the prefix so it's disabled (but still grouped together), and only the input to the right is enabled
2. if it's unclear, you could also show the full string to the right of the form as the user types

[image]

You'll find something similar to this in **[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)**

[image]

And here's the **[material version](https://material.googleplex.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-input-types)** of prefixes and suffixes (It's a bit more subtle):

[image]